# подключение css файлов в angularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

У меня приложение на angularJS. В главном файле index.html подключены соответствующие библиотеки. Стили внутри body, прописан ng-view, несколько шаблонов.

Как задавать им стили? К примеру paige1.html - я хочу подключить style1.css, я думаю надо подключать стили в главном index.html file, а что делать, если будет перекрытие стилей?

Comment: Что в Вашем понимании перекрытие стилей? Обычно разные блоки страниц имеют разные классы и, соответственно, стили. Если вы имеете в виду, что у Вас разные page (page1, page2... pageN), элементы в которых имеют имеют одинаковые названия стилей, но сами стили разные, и Вам при этом нужно для каждой страницы грузить нужный файл, то вас спасет только бандлер. Он же поможет грузить нужные контроллеры, относящиеся только к выбранной странице.

Answer (score 1):

Приложение на AngularJS подразумевает собой принцип SPA.
Следовательно, в подключаемых через `ng-view` файлах должна быть только разметка, а все основные подключаемые зависимости прописаны в главном файле `index.html`.
А чтобы для разных блоков применялись разные стили, достаточно эти блоки (и стили для них) обернуть в контейнеры, используя `class`, либо `id`.

Comment: так а если приложение вырастет огромным и где-то будут одинаковые названия классов или id

Comment: ну тут ведь принцип такой же, как и на обычных вебсайтах - одинаковые классы у одинаковых элементов... в хорошем продакшене все файлы конкатенируются по итогу в один, потому априори не должно быть повторений

Comment: всё ясно спасибо